# Converting chances to probabilities

Tags: probability

I have some data from a reference book that is given as chances per million per year.  For example, it says the chances of a catastrophic explosion occurring are 2 chances per million per year.

How do I convert this to a probability to use later in some probability calculations?

Thank you

Comment: This is problematic : It is speculative to assume that the chance that such an event occurs is the same for every single year.

Comment: Besides the looseness of the language, in general, the statement that the chances of event $E$ occurring are $2$ chances in 1 million, mathematically translates to $$p(E) = \frac{2}{1,000,000}.$$

Comment: It seems to me that there are two issues here.  First, the conversion.  Speaking loosely:  Assuming that something will occur on $n$ out of $m$ trials independently implies that the probability of it occurring on a given trial is $\frac nm$.  Second, sampling.  You are clearly dealing with an extremely rare event.  Using the sample frequency to estimate the "true" probability is unlikely to be very accurate.  I have never been struck by lighting, but that does not imply that the probability of being struck by lightning is $0$.

Comment: Thank you, think I can see the issue now.